# Using assignment with autowrap in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I am writing some code that uses sympy to construct a complicated mathematical expression, then uses the `autowrap` function to compile it and evaluate it repeatedly.

Unfortunately, my expressions are becoming exponentially large in some cases. To prevent this, I want to generate expressions that contain assignment statements. That is, I want to end up with something like (pseudocode)

```
x1 = f(a,a);
x2 = f(x1,x1);
x3 = f(x2,x2);
x4 = f(x3,x3);
```

instead of

`f(f(f(a,a),f(a,a)),f(f(a,a),f(a,a))),f(f(a,a),f(a,a)),f(f(a,a),f(a,a))))`

in which every subexpression has been substituted twice.

There seems to be a mechanism for this, in the form of [`sympy.codegen.ast.CodeBlock`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/codegen.html#sympy.codegen.ast.CodeBlock). However, I can't seem to work out how to get this to work with `autowrap`, if indeed it can.

If I attempt to do

```
>>> f = autowrap(ast.CodeBlock(ast.Assignment(y,sym.sin(x))),backend='cython')
```

then I get a long stack trace ending with

```
wrapped_code_12.c:5:22: error: use of undeclared identifier 'y'
   autofunc_result = y = sin(x);
                     ^
1 error generated.
error: command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

which suggests to me that using a CodeBlock directly inside `autowrap` isn't the right way to do it. (I get a similar error using the Fortran backend.)

The question is, is there a right way to do it? Can I use `CodeBlock` in `autowrap`, or is there some other way that I can generate intermediate variables with `autowrap` rather than always having my sympy expressions fully expanded out?

Comment: This looks more like a job for [cse](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/codegen.html#sympy.codegen.ast.CodeBlock.cse)

Comment: @WelcometoStackOverflow that would be great too, but after using cse I would still have the same problem: it returns a list of things that could be converted into assignment statements, but there seems to be no way to use assignment statements in autowrap.